# Scraping dynamically generated HTML table without an ID and Class with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I generated a table using Python Selenium and the source code of the generated table looks like the following (the code has

> ```
>         <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=806 border=0>
>     <TBODY>
>     <TR>          <TD width="603" height="25" colspan="4" align="center" bgcolor="#00596B">            
>         <b><font color="#FFFFFF">Day End Summary from Jan 03, 2019 to Jan 01, 2019</font></b>             </TD>       </TR>
>
>     <tr>
>       <TD vAlign=top align=middle width="603" style="min-height:980px;">
>         <table border="0" cellpadding="" width="603" bgcolor="#808000" cellspacing="1">
>           <tr bgcolor="#D6D6D6" height="25">
>             <td align="center"><font color="#000" size="2">#</font></td>
>           <td align="center"><font color="#000" size="2">DATE</font></td>
>           <td align="center"><font color="#000" size="2">TRADING CODE</font></td>
>             <td align="center"><font color="#000" size="2">LTP*</font></td>
>           <td align="center"><font color="#000" size="2">HIGH</font></td>
>           <td align="center"><font color="#000" size="2">LOW</font></td>
>           <td align="center"><font color="#000" size="2">OPENP*</font></td>
>           <td align="center"><font color="#000" size="2">CLOSEP*</font></td>
>           <td align="center"><font color="#000" size="2">YCP</font></td>
>           <td align="center"><font color="#000" size="2">TRADE</font></td>
>           <td align="center"><font color="#000" size="2">VALUE (mn)</font></td>
>           <td align="center"><font color="#000" size="2">VOLUME</font></td>                
>           </tr>
>
>           <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="20">
>             <td align="center"> <font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">1</font></td>
>           <td align="center"> <font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">2019-01-03</font></td>
>           <td align="left"><a href = "displayCompany.php?name=ACI" class='ab1'><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">ACI</font></a></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">328.5</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">329.9</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">323</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">325.7</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">328.4</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">325.7</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">256</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">5.285</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">16,158</font></td>
>           </tr>
>
>           <tr bgcolor="#EFEFEF" height="20">
>             <td align="center"> <font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">2</font></td>
>           <td align="center"> <font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">2019-01-02</font></td>
>           <td align="left"><a href = "displayCompany.php?name=ACI" class='ab1'><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">ACI</font></a></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">325.5</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">328.8</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">324.3</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">326</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">325.7</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">327.6</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">289</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">7.443</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">22,851</font></td>
>           </tr>
>
>           <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="20">
>             <td align="center"> <font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">3</font></td>
>           <td align="center"> <font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">2019-01-01</font></td>
>           <td align="left"><a href = "displayCompany.php?name=ACI" class='ab1'><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">ACI</font></a></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">329.1</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">329.9</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">325.6</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">329.9</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">327.6</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">326.2</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">153</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">3.234</font></td>
>           <td align="right"><font face="Arial" style="size:11px;">9,890</font></td>
>           </tr>
>
>         </table>
> ```

The link of the page is here [Dhaka Stock Exchange Historical Price](https://www.dsebd.org/day_end_archive.php). 
Now, how can I extract the full table from here? The table seems not to have any ID and Class. I am completely new to HTML and web scraping and need to do it for a project that has a very tight schedule. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

**Update:** I could extract the required table with the following code-
def extractdse(fdate, tday, instrument):

> ```
> # load the driver
> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>
> # load DSE data archive site
> driver.get('https://www.dsebd.org/day_end_archive.php')
>
> # deal with the pop up warning
> try: 
>     alert = driver.switch_to.alert
>     alert.accept()
> except NoAlertPresentException:
>     print ("No alert here")
>
> # from date
> fdate=datetime.datetime.strptime(fdate, '%Y-%m-%d')
> yr=str(fdate.year)
> mn='0'+str(fdate.month)
> dy='0'+str(fdate.day)
>
> # to date
> tday=datetime.datetime.strptime(tday, '%Y-%m-%d')
> bdd='0'+str(tday.day)
> bdm='0'+str(tday.month)
> bdy=str(tday.year)
>
> # beginning day
> x=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("DayEndSumDate1_day"))
> x.select_by_value(dy)
>
> # beginning month
> y=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("DayEndSumDate1_month"))
> y.select_by_value(mn)
>
> # beginning year
> z=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("DayEndSumDate1_year"))
> z.select_by_value(yr)
>
> # end day
> xp=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("DayEndSumDate2_day"))
> xp.select_by_value(bdd)
>
> # end month
> yp=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("DayEndSumDate2_month"))
> yp.select_by_value(bdm)
>
> # end year
> zp=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("DayEndSumDate2_year"))
> zp.select_by_value(bdy)
>
> # instrument
> inst=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("Symbol"))
> inst.select_by_visible_text(instrument)
>
> # generate the table
> driver.find_element_by_name("ViewDayEndArchive").click()
>
> # extract the table
> soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
> tables = soup.find_all('table')
> tt=tables[374]
> #ti=pd.read_html(tt)
> #tm=display_html(tt, raw=True)
> #tx=pd.read_html(tt)
> return(tt)
> ```

And now can extract the HTML code for the required table with-

> ```
> extractdse('2019-01-01', '2019-01-03', 'ACI')
> ```

Now, is there any way to convert the HTML code into Pandas Dataframe?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You probably should use pandas for this. Something like:

```
my_table = """
  [the code from your question]
 """

import pandas as pd

pad_table = pd.read_html(my_table)
pad_table
```

This should get you most of the way there.